# call onload function onload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to call the function on load the

tag.Now I can't call the function.It removed the tag and replace it with on button click.

```js
$('.test_button').click(function(){
 $('#test').remove();
 $('.panel').append('<p id="test" onload="myFunction();">No Data Available<p>');
});

function myFunction(){
alert('No data available');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
<p id="test">onload<p>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="test_button">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML elements, other than the `body`, do not have an `onload` event. Since adding elements to the DOM is synchronous, you could just invoke `myFunction` after appending. If you want the text to be changed before the alert, you can just use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

```js
$('.test_button').click(function(){
 $('#test').remove();
 $('.panel').append('<p id="test"">No Data Available<p>');
 setTimeout(myFunction);
});

function myFunction(){
    alert('No data available');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
<p id="test">onload<p>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="test_button">
```